# CSS question with cake.generic.css: Can't decrease the width of a table inside a division

Tags: html, css, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have two division with float: left;

```
div#loadwhat {
    float: left;
    width: 78%;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

div#id_div_rightside {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    border-left:solid thin #ff9900;
}
```

But the table inside loadwhat division is much wider than the loadwhat division. Why is that ?

I want to decrease the width of table. I tried to set width: xx for table but it didn't work.

In cake.generic.css

```
table {
    background: #fff;
    border-right:0;
    clear: both;
    color: #333;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Could you show us an example of your markup on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: The width of the table is bigger than the loadwhat division. So it goes to the rightside division area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try removing the table width and add `table-layout:fixed;`. This may even out the rows in many browsers.  Here is more detail: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/table-layout